# How to process a while-do loop and sort the iterated output

Tags: shell-script, sort

I'm very new at Bash Scripting so forgive my ignorance. I have a text file with last names that I am reading and processing line-by-line an average of three test scores. I need to output the lines sorted by last name. Here is what I have to compute the average, with a variable named OUTTOSORT that I was trying to pass to sort before being output.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=$1
OUTTOSORT=""

while read -r SID FIRST LAST S1 S2 S3
do
    SUM=$(expr $S1 + $S2 + $S3)
    AVG=$(expr $SUM / 3)
    OUTTOSORT = OUTTOSORT + "$AVG [$SID] $LAST, $FIRST \n"
done < "$FILE"

sort < $OUTTOSORT
```

When run:

```
engr2-6-52-dhcp:homework6 Matt$ ./Grades.sh 
./Grades.sh: line 10: : No such file or directory
./Grades.sh: line 12: $OUTTOSORT: ambiguous redirect
```

Any suggestions on how to sort these lines after computing the average would be very helpful. Thanks!

Edit:

Thanks very much for your answers! I now have a problem where it's not sorting by the field I specify however:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=$1
COUNT=0
while read -r SID FIRST LAST S1 S2 S3 
do
    SUM=$(expr $S1 + $S2 + $S3)
    AVG=$(expr $SUM / 3)
    printf '%d [%d] %s, %s (%d)\n' "$AVG" "$SID" "$LAST" "$FIRST" "$COUNT"
    COUNT=$((COUNT + 1))
done < "$FILE" | sort -k 3,3n -k 4,4n -k 2,2g
```

Output:

```
71 [299226663] Camp, Laney (5)
80 [434401929] Camp, Skyler (6)
81 [199144454] Camp, Tracey (4)
82 [123456789] Johnson, Lee (0)
82 [928441032] Forester, Jess (7)
91 [999999999] Smith, Jaime (1)
92 [888111818] Forney, JC (2)
93 [928441032] Forester, Chris (8)
99 [290010111] Lee, Terry (3)
```

As you can see, it is sorting by average score instead of by Last name, First name, SID. I added a counter to confirm it was sorting across the lines of the output. What error is causing the sort to not use the correct keys? Thanks!

Edit:

Solution to sort problem found: type flags for last name and first name should be d instead of n, making the sort command the while loop command pipes to `sort -k 3,3d -k 4,4d -k 2,2g`.

Answer (score 7):

You can print the results to standard output, then *pipe* them to the sort command:

```
while read -r SID FIRST LAST S1 S2 S3
do
     SUM=$(expr $S1 + $S2 + $S3)
     AVG=$(expr $SUM / 3)
     printf '%d [%d] %s, %s\n' "$AVG" "$SID" "$LAST" "$FIRST"
done < "$FILE" | sort
```

Comment: This helped solve my problem with Hauke Laging thank you very much!

Comment: I'd guessed this would work, but didn't feel like trying to make a smaller dataset than the one I'm working with to try it on, so this answer saved me a lot of time writing a smaller test case by verifying that it would work as I anticipated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The bugs in your code / usage are (at least):

1. The script calling: `./Grades.sh` Due to `FILE=$1` it must be `./Grades.sh /path/to/file`
2. `OUTTOSORT =` : There must not be a space on either side of the `=`
3. `OUTTOSORT = OUTTOSORT +` (1) : Variables must be referenced with a `$`, i.e. `OUTTOSORT=$OUTTOSORT`
4. `OUTTOSORT = OUTTOSORT +` (2) : There is no such string concatenation in `bash`.
5. `"...\n"` : `\n` is not an escape sequence in normal strings. You need e.g. `$'line1\n'`
6. `sort < $OUTTOSORT` : `$OUTTOSORT` must be a file here but it contains a string. You could do that with `echo "$OUTTOSORT" | sort` but easier is the combination of the `while` loop and `sort` in a pipeline as steeldriver suggested.

Comment: This helped solve my problem with steeldriver thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Once you've fixed the errors enumerated by Hauke Laging, you can get `sort` to do what you want by telling it to do a numeric sort, and to use the 3rd field (the column containing the last name) as the sort key.

`sort -n -k 3`

See `man sort` for further details.

Comment: This helped for sorting, thanks very much!